# spring.io Authenticating with LDAP guide returns Bad Credentials

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am following the guide ( https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ ) and have the following classes:

Web Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin();
}

public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                .and()
            .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
public class SpringLdapController {

@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "Welcome to the home page";
}
}
```

LDAP config file (.ldif)

```
dn: dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: springframework

dn: ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: subgroups

dn: ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: ou=space cadets,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: space cadets

dn: ou=\"quoted people\",dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: "quoted people"

dn: ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: otherpeople

dn: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Ben Alex
sn: Alex
uid: ben
userPassword: {SHA}nFCebWjxfaLbHHG1Qk5UU4trbvQ=

dn: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Bob Hamilton
sn: Hamilton
uid: bob
userPassword: bobspassword

dn: uid=joe,ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Joe Smeth
sn: Smeth
uid: joe
userPassword: joespassword

dn: cn=mouse\, jerry,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Mouse, Jerry
sn: Mouse
uid: jerry
userPassword: jerryspassword

dn: cn=slash/guy,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: slash/guy
sn: Slash
uid: slashguy
userPassword: slashguyspassword

dn: cn=quote\"guy,ou=\"quoted people\",dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: quote\"guy
sn: Quote
uid: quoteguy
userPassword: quoteguyspassword

dn: uid=space cadet,ou=space cadets,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Space Cadet
sn: Cadet
uid: space cadet
userPassword: spacecadetspassword



dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: developers
ou: developer
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
uniqueMember: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org

dn: cn=managers,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: managers
ou: manager
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
uniqueMember: cn=mouse\, jerry,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org

dn: cn=submanagers,ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: submanagers
ou: submanager
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
```

I have tried a combination of logins I thought would be correct such as:

"ben", "benspassword"||
"space cadet","spacecadetspassword"||
"jerry", "jerryspassword"

But I keep getting a "Bad Credentials" shown on my screen rejecting my login. Is there something I'm missing out?

Comment: Tested the latest version from https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ and it works. They changed the password encoding. (see that benspassword in hashed in the ldif file).

Answer (score 0):

You should have missed the application key *LDAP* properties configuration which may be gone unseen through the mentioned tutorial.

The *src/main/resources/application.properties* file should hold the embedded *Spring LDAP* server related configuration:

```
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:<YOUR_LDIF_FILE_NAME>
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=springframework,dc=org
spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
```

Note that following this sample configuration, *YOUR_LDIF_FILE_NAME* should be placed under *src/main/resources*.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. I have added the above configuration to the application.properties and the ldif is in the src/main/resources but I still have get the error. :/

Comment: Could you please add the error stacktrace to the main post?

Answer (score 0):

Passwords in your ldif file are in plaintext, and at the same time you use passwordEncoder for password comparison.